# JQuery: Access original jquery object within each

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to implement HTML radio button behaviour on a set of DIVs in JQuery. I want to remove the "set" class from all the elements then use addClass() to re-set the (one) element that is clicked:

```
$(".button").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    // what goes here to call removeClass() on *all* the elements?
    $(this).addClass("set");
  });
});
```

I want to call removeClass() on all the elements - in this case $(".button"), but I can't refer to $(".button") explicitly.

I can't just call $(".button").removeClass("set") outside the loop as this is part of a bigger program and the behaviour inside the each() loop can be modified by other parameters.

Is there any way to access the full set of elements from inside, or pass them in as a variable? Or is there another way to approach the problem?

Comment: why can't you refer to $(".button") explicitly at that point?

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin that would be called by:

    $("selector").myPlugin()

so the contents of the jquery object is going to be different each time.

Comment: Create a global var with the selector for this jquery object. And pass it in inside functions.

I do think you are making this overcomplicated, overlook your architecture and check that you know what's going on.

Comment: Why would you use each to set the click event? I really don't understand why this was repeated in all the other answers either.

Comment: Question: Why are you basically reimplementing radio buttons in CSS rather than just using the <input name="something" type="radio"> construct?

Comment: I'm making a multi-state button plug-in to make it easy to define styles for default/hover/set/active/focus states, and also to let you create buttons that behave like radio/checkboxes. I'm trying to keep it as general as possible.

I ended up with the each because as well as setting the click event I'm also setting onmouseover/onmouseout/focus/blur and they need to be defined individually or hovering over one element will highlight them all.

I tried to simplify the example to make it clearer what my problem was.

I believe that .selector is what I'm looking for, so thanks!

Comment: @R. Bemrose - radio buttons are ugly. But, they are semantically nice, and non-javascript friendly.

Comment: Although, I will note that the "correct" way to do this, is to replace existing radio buttons through javascript, not replace divs. The idea being, that if JavaScript is not available, it will gracefull degrade.

Comment: @altCognito agreed, replacing existing radio buttons would be the most unobtrusive approach. I'm hoping the plug-in will be sufficiently flexible to allow it to be used that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for the new [selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/selector) feature, since you are making a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.test = function() {
    console.log(this.selector); // .button
};

$('.button').test();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't hard-code the selector in your inner functions, jQuery can actually return the string used as selector in the original call. See [$('.bla').selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/selector)

This has been added only in the newer version though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems needlessly complex, it might help to get a clearer picture of what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Inside your loop you can fetch whatever you like with jquery $("div") // inside the loop

Comment: Oh you can set this to a variable btw.  
$(".button").each(function(){
var btn = this;
$(this).click(function(){
    btn.css("font-weight", "bold")
});

Answer (score 0):

You say "but I can't refer to $(".button") explicitly.".  Why is that?

```
$(".button").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    $('.button').removeClass('set'); // this should do it
    $(this).addClass("set");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
$(".button").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    $('.button').removeClass("set");
    $(this).addClass("set");
  });
});
```

I dont see why that would be a problem, a bit slow having to pull .button each time, but that's the only way containing in a loop like you want to.

Comment: I don't see why I got flagged down?

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question asked in the body of the text: If you want to set the class of every ***other*** element that's a sibling, use siblings.

[Interesting because this is in the roadmap under radioClass()](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap#Attributes_.2F_CSS)

What you want is [siblings](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings), and don't use each to set the click event either.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('set');
  $(this).siblings('.button').removeClass('set');
});
```

See this example for the above in action:

http://jsbin.com/ewiqe

Comment: Thank you, yes that is what I had in mind. One issue I see is that if their were other (none button) elements at the same DOM level they might be selected too.

Comment: @simoncoggins True! I updated it to use the class selector so that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why you cannot reference $('.button') from the inner function but can you capture the references in a free variable instead?

```
var buttons = $(".button");
buttons.each(function() {
  $(this).click(function(){
    // what goes here to call removeClass() on *all* the elements?
    buttons.removeClass('set');
    $(this).addClass("set");
  });
});
```

Comment: Posted the same thing, Dmitri Farkov replied "Callback function has its own scope so No."